# How to remove or strip images in email signatures in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, blocking, email-signature

I get really annoyed by people, clients or companies putting images in their signatures, be it small or large images or nowadays animated gifs.

Is there a setting or add-on for Thunderbird to hide, strip or remove:

a) ...the complete signature inside an email?

b) ...hide/block/remove all images inside a signature of an email?

c) ...hide all embedded images inside emails if none of the above work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way by using `userContent.css` in Thunderbird.

Create the folder `chrome` in your profile folder and place the file `userContent.css` inside.

Add images, styles, whatever to it, to hide all gif images i.e.:

```
img[src*=".gif"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Or keep a list of files you want to hide:

```
img[src*="stupid-animation.gif"],
img[src*="disturbing-ad.jpg"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Restart Thunderbird, enjoy.